# Function to see how many plugins on a site need updating

Tags: plugins, updates

I manage a lot of WordPress websites and want to create a system that allows me to check how many plugins on a given site need updating.

So basically what I need is a custom function that returns the number of plugins that are out of date and need updating. I have searched the developer documentation but cannot find a specific function that does this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your "system" as a whole is intended to look like but the function you want is [`wp_update_plugins()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_plugins/) in [`wp-includes/update.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/update.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had found this function before but am unsure how to use it; where exactly does it need to be used? When I run it in a theme for testing purposes, it doesn't output anything. Also, if I assign it to a variable and var_dump that variable, I get an output of NULL

Comment: I will edit with some code.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) for this. It has many handy commands including [plugin](http://wp-cli.org/commands/plugin/list/) related. Hope this helps!